# Why this template parameters con­straint doesn't work?

Tags: templates, d

Reading [templates-revisited](http://dlang.org/templates-revisited.html):

```
struct S(T : T*) {
  T t;  // t is supposed to be of type 'int*', but it's of type 'int', why?
}

void main() {

  int x = 123;
  S!(int*) s;
  static assert(is(typeof(s.t) == typeof(&x)));
}
```

The above code doesn't compile.

Strangely enough, the following does compile:

```
struct S(T : int*) {
  T t;
}

void main() {

  int x = 123;
  S!(int*) s;
  static assert(is(typeof(s.t) == typeof(&x)));
}
```

I don't understand this behavior.  An explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: and if you try  `struct S(T:void*)`

Comment: I would point out that those assertions won't work (certainly, they don't on 2.059), because you can't compare types. You need them to be in an `is` expression.

Comment: @JonathanMDavis Regardless, doing `s.t = &x` in the first example does NOT work and I get `Error: cannot implicitly convert expression (& x) of type int* to int`.  So I guess this is a DMD bug?

Comment: @Arlen I'm not disputing the question itself. It's clear enough what you mean, and the problem is indeed there if you use a proper `is` expression. I'm just pointing out that the assertions are incorrect as they stand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a type specialization (the type after the colon) is dependent on the parameter identifier, such as `T : T*`, the resulting identifier refers to the role of the identifier (`T`) in the type specialization (the *deduced* type) if there was a match.

Otherwise, if the specialization is independent, such as `T : int*`, the resulting identifier is an alias of the type specialization.

Examples:

```
=========================================================
Argument T        | Specialization     | Result
=========================================================
void              | T : void           | void
char              | T : void           | <no match>
int*              | T : T*             | int
immutable(char)[] | T : T[]            | immutable(char)
immutable(char)[] | T : immutable(T)[] | char
=========================================================
```

When there is a mismatch for an argument passed to a template parameter, the template is dropped from the overload set. An error is raised if the overload set becomes empty before a match is found.

When there is a mismatch in an [IsExpression](http://dlang.org/expression.html#IsExpression) (the `is(...)` primary expression), the result is false and no symbols are introduced into scope.

Answer (score 3):

As explained in the Argument Deduction section of http://dlang.org/template.html, when deducing the types of template arguments:

> 1. If there is no type spe­cial­iza­tion for the pa­ra­me­ter, the type of the pa­ra­me­ter is set to the tem­plate ar­gu­ment.
> 2. If the type spe­cial­iza­tion is de­pen­dent on a type pa­ra­me­ter, the type of that pa­ra­me­ter is set to be the
>      cor­re­spond­ing part of the type ar­gu­ment.
> 3. If after all the type ar­gu­ments are ex­am­ined there are any type pa­ra­me­ters left with no type as­signed, they are as­signed types
>      cor­re­spond­ing to the tem­plate ar­gu­ment in the same po­si­tion in
>      the Tem­plateAr­gu­mentList.
> 4. If ap­ply­ing the above rules does not re­sult in ex­actly one type for each tem­plate pa­ra­me­ter, then it is an error.

And the example that corresponds to your case is:

```
template TBar(T : T*) { }
alias TBar!(char*) Foo3;   // (2) T is deduced to be char
```

So, what you're seeing in your first example is expected behavior. Because the `T` is on both sides, `T` ends up being evaluated to what would result in the template argument being `T*`. So, since the template argument is `int*`, `T*` would be `int*`, and `T` ends up being `int`. What you have is very similar to [`std.traits.pointerTarget`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_traits#pointerTarget):

```
/**
Returns the target type of a pointer.
*/
template pointerTarget(T : T*)
{
    alias T pointerTarget;
}
```

Your second example compiles, because that template is requiring that `T` be implicitly convertible to `int*`. And since `int*` is implicitly convertible to itself, when you pass `int*` as the template argument, it works. What's causing you trouble is when `T` is on both sides, because then the right-hand side of the expression is dependent on the left.

Now, I assume that what you actually intend to test here is that the template argument is a pointer? If that's the case, then you should use [`std.traits.isPointer`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_traits.html#isPointer):

```
struct S(T)
    if(isPointer!T)
{
    T t;
}
```